# Cannot run web project with GAE

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I just started making a a new web project using GAE SDK without GWT but in the console all I get is this:

```
WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@689a1f91{/,C:\Users\Mike\workspace\project\war}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No such servlet: default
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.updateMappings(ServletHandler.java:1026)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.setServletMappings(ServletHandler.java:1110)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initialize(WebXmlConfiguration.java:306)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:180)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1247)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:196)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:239)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:146)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:173)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:120)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:96)
```

Here is web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>dispatcher</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you post your `web.xml` file? It looks the problem might be in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you have a mapping to a servlet called default:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but no servlet called that. This is the only servlet defined:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

as you are using spring its likely that you don't need the default servlet, as spring will probably be responsible for dispatching your requests to the correct handler.   If you remove the first block of code above you should be ok.

I'm assuming you are using Spring MVC.  If so you either need to set spring up to scan for components so it can pick up your annotated controllers to handle requests or set the mapping to the controllers up manually.